# unexpected AST Node

Tags: hibernate, hql, nhibernate-hql

I use the below given HQL Query:

```
select A.id.customerName,
       A.id.customerId,
       A.id.IZone,
       B.id.accountType,
       B.id.accountNumber,
       B.id.bankBranch,
       (DAYS(current_date)-DAYS(B.id.enrolledDate)) -
       (select count(distinct C.id.DWkhol) from Holiday C
        where C.id.ICo='01' and
              C.id.DWkhol between B.id.enrolledDate and current_date)
from Profile A, Account B
where B.id.accountNumber != ' ' and
      A.id.customerId= B.id.customerId;
```

Same query works fine in SQL developer and i am able to see the values. 
But I am receiving expections when i call this Query through my java class:

> [3/16/17 21:02:29:624 EDT] 00000027 SystemOut     O 406868
>   [WebContainer : 1] ERROR org.hibernate.hql.PARSER  - :0:0:
>   unexpected AST node: query [3/16/17 21:02:29:626 EDT] 00000027
>   SystemOut     O 406868 [WebContainer : 1] DEBUG
>   org.hibernate.hql.ast.ErrorCounter  - :0:0: unexpected AST node:
>   query :0:0: unexpected AST node: query   at
>   org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.expr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1312)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.arithmeticExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2749)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2006)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectExprList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1825)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1394)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:553)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:281)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:229)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:251)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:183)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:13
>   [3/16/17 21:02:29:626 EDT] 00000027 SystemOut     O 406870
>   [WebContainer : 1] ERROR org.hibernate.hql.PARSER  -  right-hand
>   operand of a binary operator was null [3/16/17 21:02:29:627 EDT]
>   00000027 SystemOut     O 406870 [WebContainer : 1] DEBUG
>   org.hibernate.hql.ast.ErrorCounter  -  right-hand operand of a binary
>   operator was null  right-hand operand of a binary operator was null
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.BinaryArithmeticOperatorNode.initialize(BinaryArithmeticOperatorNode.java:48)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker.prepareArithmeticOperator(HqlSqlWalker.java:1033)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.arithmeticExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2756)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2006)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectExprList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1825)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1394)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:553)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:281)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:229)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:251)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:183)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:134)

Comment: `DAYS` looks like a Sybase function, and I doubt that would be supported by HQL.  Please update your question and tell us what database you are using and what this query is supposed to be doing.

Comment: Hello Tim Beigeleisn, Database is DB2 and the query retrieves customer details from profile and account tables where their account number is not null and also it calculates how long they are holding their account. Duration in days.

Comment: I don't think you can use `DAYS`.  Rephrase your query.

Comment: DAYS is not an isssue, because when i just used DAYS(current_date)-DAYS(B.id.enrolledDate) it was giving me some value. When i include the calculation of reducing total number of holidays in a year problem occurs.

Comment: Total number of days holiday from enrolled date and current date.         select count(distinct C.id.DWkhol) from Holiday C where C.id.ICo='01' and C.id.DWkhol between B.id.enrolledDate and current_date

Comment: without using Days is there a way i can calculate total number of days??? I am not sure how it can be done in HQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HQL does not support the `DAYS()` function, which is a DB2 specific function.  However, from the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions) it should support `EXTRACT()`, assuming the underlying database supports it, which is the case for DB2.  So, you should be able to replace this portion of your query:

```
DAYS(current_date) - DAYS(B.id.enrolledDate)
```

with this:

```
EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM current_date) - EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM B.id.enrolledDate) / 60*60*24
```

Extracting the epoch for a date yields the number of seconds since Jan 1, 1970.  We then convert this to days by dividing by `60*60*24`.

Comment: I tried the above. Its giving me Grammar Exception. I am not able to proceed with this. Actually the problem is not with Current date - enrolledDate calculation. Problem begins when i add this: (select count(distinct C.id.DWkhol) from Holiday C
        where C.id.ICo='01' and
              C.id.DWkhol between B.id.enrolledDate and current_date)